# no hosts matched : vagrant with ansible

Tags: ansible, vagrant

For test purposes I've configured a combination of vagrant/virtualbox/ansible.

Versions >>  Ansible : 2.3.1.0 | Vagrant : 1.9.5.

While running :

```
vagrant provision
```

the output states :

```
  web1: Running provisioner: ansible...
  web1: Running ansible-playbook...
  PLAY [Install Apache] 
  **********************************************************
   skipping: no hosts matched
   PLAY RECAP 
  ****************************************************************
```

Below the configuration files :

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.define "web1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8040, host: 8090
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "256"
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
  end
  end
  end
```

Playbook :

```
  ---
  - name: Install Apache
    hosts: testclients
    become_user: root
    roles:
      - apache
```

Andible inventory (/etc/ansible/hosts) :

```
 [testclients]
 testclient3
```

and successful checking

```
  ansible -m ping testclients
  testclient3 | SUCCESS => {
  "changed": false,
  "ping": "pong"
    }
```

The weird thing is that if i will run the playbook itself (ansible-playbook playbook.yml) it works, in contrary inside vagrant which doesn't and return "no hosts matched".
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you have your own inventory file but you do not instruct vagrant to use it, add the inventory_path properties in the ansible block with the path of the file to be used

Comment: ok ,thanks for your comment.I added those 2 lines in Vagrantfile :   
    ansible.inventory_path = "provisioning/hosts"
    ansible.limit = "all"  .  While trying to re-run playbook ,an error occurs : TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
fatal: [testclient3]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'testclient3,192.168.111.111' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nPermission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mismatch as you do not declare the inventory file to be used by Vagrant so it returns no host matched for testclients.

You have following options to fix your issue

1. naive option: just use all hosts so everything will be ok

In your Playbook definition, change the host definition

```
  ---
  - name: Install Apache
    hosts: all
    become_user: root
```

Even if its not what you want at the end, give it a try just to make sure everything is working fine.

2. Instruct vagrant to use your inventory file

In your Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
    ansible.inventory_path = "path_to_your_file"
  end
```

You need to make sure you inform how to reach the instance so you need your inventory to have

```
testclient3 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200 ansible_ssh_user='vagrant' ansible_ssh_private_key_file='path to ssh key'
```

3. do not include your own inventory file and let vagrant generate one for you.

You will need vagrant to set the [groups](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#groups)

```
  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
    ansible.groups = {
      "testclients" => ["testclient3"]
    }
  end
```

vagrant will generate the inventory file

Comment: thanks Frederic ,it works indeed.One last question : in 3rd option ,how vagrant knows which username/password will use in order to connect to VM and apply the playbook if i omit all the connection details in /etc/ansible/hosts ? thanks in advance

Comment: vagrant auto-generate the inventory file based on the information it knows (see https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro.html#the-inventory-file)